Why Lord Krishna adorns a peacock feather?
I want scriptural references that make mention of Lord Krishna adorning a peacock feather and perhaps also, why? Please let me know.

Do you perhaps mean "he is adorned with peacock feather" (he wears it), rather than "he adorns a peacock feather" (he decorates it with something)?


अपने मुकुट को मोर पंख से सजाकर, भगवान कृष्ण प्रतीकात्मक रूप से अहंकार पर अपनी विजय, विनम्रता और अनुग्रह के अवतार का प्रतीक बन जाते हैं।


Translation as below
In Hinduism, Lord Krishna is revered as the eighth avatar of Lord Vishnu, the preserver of the universe. He is depicted in various forms, each carrying symbolic significance. The peacock feather on Lord Krishna's crown holds profound symbolism that resonates with his divine attributes and the lessons he imparts to humanity.
One interpretation of the peacock feather's significance is its association with victory over the ego and pride. In Hindu mythology, the peacock is often depicted as a symbol of beauty, grace, and resilience. However, the peacock's cry is said to resemble the sound of a distressed cry, representing the call of the ego. By adorning his crown with a peacock feather, Lord Krishna symbolically signifies his triumph over the ego and his embodiment of humility and grace.
Additionally, the peacock feather is associated with Lord Krishna's playful and mischievous nature. In Hindu scriptures such as the Bhagavata Purana, Lord Krishna is depicted as a divine child who delights in playing pranks and engaging in playful activities with his devotees and companions, such as the gopis (cowherd girls). The colorful and vibrant peacock feather reflects Lord Krishna's joyous and playful essence, reminding devotees of the importance of embracing lightheartedness and joy in life.
Moreover, the peacock feather is also linked to Lord Krishna's association with nature and the environment. In Hindu cosmology, nature is revered as a manifestation of the divine, and Lord Krishna is often depicted surrounded by lush forests and vibrant flora and fauna. The peacock feather symbolizes Lord Krishna's connection to the natural world and his role as the protector of all living beings.
Overall, the significance of Lord Krishna adorning his crown with a peacock feather encompasses themes of humility, playfulness, and reverence for nature. Through this symbolic gesture, Lord Krishna teaches devotees important spiritual lessons and inspires them to cultivate qualities such as humility, joy, and reverence for the natural world in their own lives.
References:
Bhagavad Gita, Chapter 10, Verse 30: Lord Krishna declares, "Among birds, I am the son of Vinata [Garuda], and among flying things, I am the wind. Among the purifiers, I am the wind, of the wielders of weapons, I am Rama [Balarama], among fishes, I am the shark, and of flowing rivers, I am the Ganges."
Bhagavata Purana, Section 10: The Bhagavata Purana contains numerous stories and descriptions of Lord Krishna's divine pastimes, including his playful interactions with devotees and his embodiment of divine qualities

A playful decoration. Farmers in Bavaria, Germany decorate their traditional hats with bird feathers.

I'd like to add, there's no reason why Krishna wears a peacock feather.
If there would be a cause, then Krishna would be subject to it, and hence controlled by that cause which would make that cause more powerful than God himself. This is why, all the forms of bhagavān are eternal and causeless. They do not have a reason to appear as they do.
Krishna wears a peacock feather because he can and he wants to. Similarly, while we can speculate why Lord Vishnu has 4 arms and a specific appearance, we cannot really point out when he decided to appear that way and know the reason for sure. He's allowed to do anything and he chooses to appear this way. Maybe he wants it to mean something, but God does not really care about show.

I'm not sure why the answer was downvoted. It's a simple nyāya-like argument for the existence of sac-cid-ananda form. If someone thinks these forms are just metaphorical or allegorical or symbolical, they'd have to show actual evidence in the scriptures where it's said that.

Ultimately, there is no cause for anything, Lord Krishna is the cause for everything. Whatever other causal relationships we establish in the material realm is actually an effective causal relationship which is also provided by Lord Himself so that we are able to navigate our way in this world. So, even if there is no cause for Lord Krishna to adorn a peacock feather, He will still provide us with one in so that we navigate our way through this world to Him.

@Dr.user44690 Yes, that is what I mention as well. He does give us hints so that we can find a reason but ultimately, there's no reason: "while we can speculate why Lord Vishnu has 4 arms and a specific appearance, we cannot really point out when he decided to appear that way and know the reason for sure"
